# append class to div not working

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have the following div :

```
<div class="overlay">
    <a title="yes" href="#"><div class="yes"></div></a>
    <a title="no" href="#"><div class="no"></div></a>
</div>

<div class="movie item-parent">
    <a title="Sin city" class="movie-link">
        <img src="images/1.jpg" />
    </a>
    <div class="overlay">
        <a title="yes" href="#"><div class="yes"></div></a>
        <a title="no" href="#"><div class="no"></div></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

If the user clicks on 'no', Sin city is replaced by another movie present in newproducts.jsp like this :

```
<div class="movie item-parent">
    <a title="The Hobbit" class="movie-link">
        <img src="images/2.jpg" />
    </a>
    <div class="overlay">
        <a title="yes" href="#"><div class="yes"></div></a>
        <a title="no" href="#"><div class="no"></div></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

My jquery code is :

```
$('.no').on("click", function(){
    var parent_movie= $(this).parent('.movie');
    parent_movie.empty();
    parent_movie.load("reco_product_stream.jsp a"); 
    parent_movie.append($('.overlay'));
});
```

But the movie isnt getting replaced.

If I change `.parent` to `.parents`, the movie gets replaced fine but the `.overlay` is removed from all other movies on the page, and doesnt come back despite the `.append`.

Comment: I have another `div.overlay` outside the .movie for that. I am just emptying the .movie div, so the append should still work, no ? It doesnt seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.no').on("click", function(){
    var $parent_movie = $(this).closest('.movie');
    $.get('reco_product_stream.jsp', function(data) {
        var $a = $(data).find('a'); 
        $parent_movie.children('a').replaceWith($a); 
    })
});
```

Comment: It doesnt seem to find the `a` tag. I did a `alert($a.attr("title"));` and it alerts **undefined**, even though there's just single a tag in the requested file.

Comment: @soundswaste Try using `console.log(data)` and check the output. If there is only an `a` tag use `replaceWith(data)`.

Comment: It returns this : `<body>

<a title="As Good As It Gets (1997)" class="movie-link"><img src="images/4.jpg" /></a>
</body>`

Comment: Yes, there was just 1 `a` tag. So i enclosed it in a div and did a `find('a')` and works perfectly now. Thanks, your solution is brilliant overall!

Answer (score 2):

Use `closest()` instead of `parent()`  as parent looks immediate parent and closest looks up the dom for first match.

```
var parent_movie= $(this).closest('.movie');
```

Comment: Tried that. Its stil clearing the `.overlay` from all the movies on the page. The `.load` works fine though.

Comment: Try using clone to keep the orignal object as it is, parent_movie.append($('.overlay').clone);

Answer (score 0):

Your line of code:

```
var parent_movie = $(this).parent('.movie');
```

looks only at the immediate parent and only matches if that immediate parent has a class `movie`.  Since that is not the case in your HTML, this results in an empty jQuery object so the subsequent lines of code do nothing.

Since you want to search up the parent chain until you find a `movie` class,  use this instead:

```
var parent_movie = $(this).closest('.movie');
```

Comment: Tried that. Its stil clearing the `.overlay` from all the movies on the page. The `.load` works fine though.

Comment: @soundswaste - you have multiple `.overlay` items and your code targets all of them.  You probably need to target only a specific `.overlay` element, but I don't know if you want to move one to be a child or want to add a new one that is a clone so I can't recommend specific code.  Your question provides no details on this aspect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
var parent_movie = $(this).closest('.movie');
```